# Exception in Pepper-Box PlainText Config for big size Jsons

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I am trying to send big size Jsons through Pepper-Box Plain Text Config and getting exception:

```
java.lang.ClassFormatError: Truncated class file
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:642) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
at com.gslab.pepper.input.compile.DynamicClassLoader.findClass(DynamicClassLoader.java:59) ~[pepper-box-1.0.jar:?]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[?:1.8.0_172]
at com.gslab.pepper.input.compile.InMemoryJavaCompiler.compileSchemaClass(InMemoryJavaCompiler.java:46) ~[pepper-box-1.0.jar:?]
at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaTranslator.getPlainTextMsgIterator(SchemaTranslator.java:47) ~[pepper-box-1.0.jar:?]
at com.gslab.pepper.input.SchemaProcessor.getPlainTextMessageIterator(SchemaProcessor.java:36) ~[pepper-box-1.0.jar:?]
at com.gslab.pepper.loadgen.impl.PlaintTextLoadGenerator.<init>(PlaintTextLoadGenerator.java:34) ~[pepper-box-1.0.jar:?]
at com.gslab.pepper.config.plaintext.PlainTextConfigElement.iterationStart(PlainTextConfigElement.java:53) ~[pepper-box-1.0.jar:?]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterationStart(GenericController.java:399) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.fireIterEvents(GenericController.java:391) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.GenericController.next(GenericController.java:160) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.control.LoopController.next(LoopController.java:135) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.AbstractThreadGroup.next(AbstractThreadGroup.java:92) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:255) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.2.1]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_172]
```

Answer (score 0):

1. If the issue reproduces with smaller JSON - it might be the case JSON syntax clashes with [Schema Template Functions](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#schema-template-functions)
2. If the issue reproduces with large JSON - you can raise an [issue](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box/issues) in the [Pepper-Box - Kafka Load Generator](https://github.com/GSLabDev/pepper-box#pepper-box---kafka-load-generator) project. In the meantime you can send messages to Kafka brokers using [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler) and Groovy language, example code would be something like:

   ```
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.KafkaProducer
   import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord

   def props = new Properties();
   props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");
   props.put("acks", "all");
   props.put("retries", 0);
   props.put("batch.size", 16384);
   props.put("linger.ms", 1);
   props.put("buffer.memory", 33554432);
   props.put("key.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");
   props.put("value.serializer", "org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer");

   def producer = new KafkaProducer<>(props);
   int partition = 5;
   1.upto(100, { counter ->
       producer.send(new ProducerRecord<>("your-topic", partition, "foo-" + counter, new File('/path/to/your/big.json').text);
   })

   producer.close();
   ```

More information:

- [Kafka Producer and Consumer Examples Using Java](https://dzone.com/articles/kafka-producer-and-consumer-example)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)